# How do I select proper action in the dialog "Resharper - Shortcut Conflict" for a shortcut?

Tags: visual-studio, resharper

When I press ctrl+R, ctr+R, a dialog comes up

[image: resharper conflict dialog]

Lets assume that I want to map the shortcut to "Refactor.Rename".

When I clicked OK here, the action was not mapped to the shortcut.
Instead the shortcut became disabled as in not being "available".

Resetting all shortcuts to visual studio defaults and doing this again actually gave me the resharper action upon pressing Ctrl+R, Ctrl+R.

Does it matter when I select in this list before I press OK?
If I select something in the list and also make a radio button selection, what will be the result?

Is there any way for me to use this dialog to select an action without resetting all shortcuts to either visual studio defaults or resharper defaults?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

List selection doesn't matter and only radio button selection makes sence. There is no reference to list selection in [documentation](https://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/help/Configuring_Keyboard_Shortcuts.html).

The "shortcut became disabled as in not being "available"" message is displayed even if your code window lost its focus. Are you sure the shortcut really was broken?

Comment: Is "Use Visual Studio commands" meaning "Use the Visual Studio command"? Do you know what the message that the shortcut is not available means if not that the shortcut is somewhat broken?

Comment: @AndersLindén "Use Visual Studio commands" means that the default VS command (Refactor.Rename) will be called and the R# command (ReSharper.ReSharper_Rename) will not be called. If you selected an option and after that rename window is not appear (neither VS window nor R# window)
when you are trying to rename class name or variable - then YES, something is wrong. 
It is easy to check and fix in `Tools - Options - Environment - Keyboard`: just select "Text Editor" scope and press a key combination. `Ctrl+R, Ctrl+R` should be assigned to Refactor.Rename or ReSharper.ReSharper_Rename.

Comment: Do you know what the shortcut not being available means? The normal tip in that case is that one should reset all shortcuts to either vs or reshaper. How can it not be available and is there another way to solve the issue than restoring all shortcuts, not just the one causing the problem?